# Handling concurrency in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, concurrency

I'm creating an API that interacts with a MySQL inventory database. We have 15 users that can reserve products, updating the database in the following way:

- Decreasing the `on-hand` value and increasing the `reserved` value of a product.

The `inventory` table looks like this:

```
id        int
sku       varchar
on-hand   int
reserved  int
```

The problem is: How to handle the update of the row if 2 users try to update it at the same time?

The first aproach i was thinking about was using [Transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#database-transactions):

```
<?php
    function reserveStock()
    {
        $db->beginTransaction();

        // SELECT on-hand, reserved from inventory

        // Update inventory values

        $db->commit();

        return response()->json([ 'success' => 1, 'data' => $data ])
    }
```

The second one was using [pessimist locking](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#pessimistic-locking):

```
<?php
    function reserveStock()
    {

        // SELECT on-hand, reserved from inventory with ->sharedLock()

        // Update inventory values

        return response()->json([ 'success' => 1, 'data' => $data ])
    }
```

The third one was to create a `updating` field with a value of cero. When selecting the products to update, i'd check the `updating` field before doing anything with that rows. The problem i see here is that i'd have to loop the ones with `updating != 0` until they become available. More selects and updates come fromt his aproach.

Which course of action if the best? There may be more options than the ones i've wrote here.

Comment: No approach will help you battle against 2 people updating at same time. The 2nd update will be queued and executed after 1st one. You will always end up with the data from the user who was the last to update. This isn't related to laravel but database design. You need a history table that will show you what each user did to the stock. Calculation you're after is summing or deducting or whatever is required using the history table. With 15 users, chance that two will "fight" for the exclusive right to update is almost 0. You need to make it more robust.

Comment: We've actually designed the database with a history table (kardex), but i was thinking, at some point, the table will be thousands of rows, slowing the proccess because it must recalculate the value. @N.B. What do you think?

Comment: If you said billions of rows, then that would be a bit problematic. Thousands.. not so much. You also don't have to always go through the entire table to get the numbers out, you can always materialize the stock count at some point and continue from there. If you deal with stock, you **need** to have the history table to be able to track the stock. If you use history table, you can always know what count you need to have (if you have 10 in stock, 2 were sold and 1 was damaged, you have 7 to sell - you can enforce integrity checks on that).

Comment: We got that covered. We have the `Inventory` table which contains the actual values; the `Kardex` table which contains all the movements and operations, and the `History` table that contains the values of the affected rows before and after operations.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like you are set - I wouldn't worry too much about performance at this stage. If your data model is set up correctly, you will be able to scale it. It's more important to have accurate numbers than to shave off a few milliseconds here and there.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use neither transactions no pessimist locking.

Do not use update either.

For racing condition situation you better review your database, and get rid of update, use insert instead. Make a pivot table to accomodate connection between users and products. And make only first connecting record (where id is smaller) to be the actual one.

If more explanation needed, here it is an **example**:

Say 2 users racing to get the product. They both create records in the pivot table, almost simultaneously but someone should be firs, right? They both committing very small transaction to persist their data. And then - they both read the pivot table to verify who is succeeded. The first record will be the same for both of them, there would be no blocking in use (at lease explicit). So one customer will get his record and be happy, the other one is going to be reapply to get another product.

And problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but I can help a person like me who came with a similar issue.
You can solve this by using jobs/queues. That way no 'transaction' related to a user will run 'the same time' as another. Consider checking this article about [Concurrency attack](https://blog.tobexkee.com/handling-concurrency-attacks-in-laravel) and I am sure you will appreciate.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33198855)

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    // Start a transaction
    $mysqli->begin_transaction();

    // Fetch the record with a lock for update
    $productId = 1; // Replace with the actual product ID
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE product_id = $productId FOR UPDATE");

    if (!$result) {
        // Handle query error
        throw new Exception("Error fetching record for update");
    }

    // Fetch the data from the result set
    $inventory = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if (!$inventory) {
        // Handle product not found
        throw new Exception("Product not found");
    }

    // Perform checks and update the record
    // ...

    // Commit the transaction
    $mysqli->commit();

    echo "Product updated successfully";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Rollback the transaction on error
    $mysqli->rollback();

    // Handle the exception, log it, or return an appropriate response
    echo "Failed to update product: " . $e->getMessage();
} finally {
    // Close the MySQLi connection
    $mysqli->close();
}`enter code here`
```